# How WordPress sends emails using native mail() function, while function itself doesn't work?

Tags: php, wordpress

This question is more about PHP, rather than WP.

I call built-in function `mail()` on a hosting provider. It always returns `FALSE`, while on local machine it returns `TRUE`.

```
<?php

$result = mail(...);

var_dump($result) // always false on a provider machine;
```

So I know and **expect** that `mail()` shouldn't work on a host machine. But when installing a WP from a package, it somehow sends "Welcome to WordPress" mail from the domain it runs on.

The core code of WP is a pure mess, and it's not that easy to read and understand it. But when exploring it I noted that it uses `mail()` function to send welcome mails. So what I'm asking is how WP **magically** configures that `mail()` function to send mails?

Comment: It's easier to understand the WordPress core (and how plugins work) if you keep in mind that it is primarily event driven, similar to how you would think of Javascript and callbacks except you are making calls to `add_action()` and `add_filter()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress's [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function [uses PHPMailer](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L216).